# Ist deutsche Gebärdensprache on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Aus gegebenem Anlass (diese Frage wurde angezweifelt):

["Einen guten Rutsch" in Gebärdensprache](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48583/einen-guten-rutsch-in-geb%C3%A4rdensprache)

Comment: Wie sehen das denn die anderen Sprachen-SX? Englisch hat bspw. das Problem, dass amerikanische (ASL) und britische (BSL) Gebärdensprache *sehr* verschieden sind. Das Problem haben wir nicht. Eine eigene Seite für alle Gebärdensprachen gibt es m. W. nicht, könnte aber sinnvoll sein.

Comment: @crissov soweit ich weiß, unterscheiden sich die Regiolekte der deutschen Gebärdensprache (evtl. aufgrund relativ geschlossener Nutzergruppen?) *sehr*. Ist das vergleichbar mit dem Unterschied zwischen ASL und BSL?

Comment: Nein, ASL ist enger mit der französischen Gebärdensprache verwandt als mit BSL. DGS hat lediglich Dialekte.

Comment: Nur zur Ergänzung: sign-languages werden derzeit auf [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explizit als _on-topic_ gelistet. Je nachdem, wie diese Abstimmung hier ausfällt, könnten wir auf unserer Help-page dorthin verweisen/-linken.

Comment: @Marzipanherz [linguistics.se] has a policy to close and delete questions for being "language specific questions on usage or translation". Für die meisten Fragen zur deutschen Gebärdensprache kommt es daher nicht in Frage.

Comment: @jknappen Heißt das, sie meinen nur ASL und BSL, wenn sie auf der Seite von _sign language_ reden?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Nein, das heißt, das sehr viele Fragen (z.B. die nach konkreten Gebärden für eine Bedeutung oder die Übersetzung konkreter Gebärden) für alle Gebärdensprachen off-topic sind. Linguistische Fragen zu Gebärdensprachen sind zu allen Gebärdensprachen erlaubt.

Answer (score 5):

Gebärdensprache hat eine andere grammatische Struktur als Deutsch, außerdem natürlich ein anderes Vokabular. Dass es eine deutsche Gebärdensprache gibt, ist kein Argument dafür, sie als Teil der deutschen Sprache (im Sinne einer den indogermanischen Sprachen zugehörigen Sprache, also »Deutsch«) zu betrachten.

Deshalb gebe ich PiedPiper recht: Fragen zur Gebärdensprache sind nicht Thema dieser Seite.

Comment: Klar -1. Hier geht es uns mE um die deutsche Sprache, deren mündliche und schriftliche Aspekten wir im Üblichen betrachten. Gebärdensprache ist aber ein anderer Ausdruck des Deutschen; nur den braucht eine Minderheit. Diskriminierung beiseite ist dein Argument irrtümlich. Wenn die Entfernung zwischen den Strukturen des Deutschen und seiner Gäberdensprache ein Ausschlußkriterion ist, so wäre die Ähnlichkeit zwischen dem Niederländischen und dem Deutschen auch ein Grund, Niederländisch hier zu erlauben. Wenn das Vokabular auch mit dem Deutschen übereinstimmen muss, so wären Jiddisch off-topic.

Comment: @c.p. Ich bin kein Linguist, aber DGS hat meines Erachtens mehr mit ASL gemein, als mit der deutschen Lautsprache. "Deutsch" in "Deutsche Gebärdensprache" ist lediglich ein lokaler Bezug. Die Sprache ist vollkommen eigenständig. DGS ist nicht die deutsche Lautsprache mit anderen Mitteln, so wie ich hier eine Verschriftlichung der deutschen Lautsprache verwende, sondern eine komplett eigenständige Sprache, ohne großen Bezug zur sie "umgebenden" Lautsprache. Diese Bezüge sind höchstens als Fremd- oder Lehnworte zu betrachten... - Daher klar +1!

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Ich wollte vor Tagen Ähnliches schreiben, aber ich denke nicht, dass c.p. hier diesem Irrtum unterliegt. Ich verstehe seinen Kommentar eher so, dass DGS gerade aufgrund der örtlichen Nähe (Sprecher der DGS sind prinzipiell eher Nutzer von German.SE als Sprecher der französischen Gebärdensprache) hier *on-topic* ist. Das gilt unter dem Aspekt des Arguments von Wrzlprmft (s. u.), dass wir hier eher eine »Community von Nutzern« sind als »Besucher einer Seite zu einem Thema«, und dass das »German« nicht zu eng gefasst werden sollte.

Comment: @c.p. Trotzdem bin ich mit dem Seitenhieb der Diskrimierung nicht einverstanden. Wenn schon solche Vorwürfe ausgepackt werden, dann bitte auch mit Ausführung!

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek edit: Ich las gerade c.p.s neue Antwort (von gestern) und sehe, dass c.p.s Kommentar doch so gemeint ist, wie du interpretiert hast.

Answer (score 5):

### On topic

**...sofern sich eine Verbindung zur gesprochenen oder geschriebenen deutschen Sprache herstellen lässt** <sup>(das sollte eigentlich selbstverständlich sein, aber angesichts der Kommentare und anderen Antworten hier scheint es doch nicht so klar zu sein)</sup>

Gebärdensprache ist eine von vielen Ausdrucksformen einer **Sprache**. Ein grundlegender Unterschied zu *on topic* Fragen nach z.B. Mundart, regionaler Aussprache, Typographie oder Handschrift besteht nicht.

Wir haben angesichts der nur geringen Anzahl von Fragen keine Not, sorgfältig gestellte Fragen prinzipiell auszuschließen.

Das Argument, wir hätten keine Experten auf diesem Gebiet könnte man auf alle möglichen anderen Fragen, inklusive Fragen zu Jargon genauso bringen. Da würde ich sagen: *schau'n wir mal*. Wenn sich dann nach mehreren Fragen herausstellt, dass niemand eine Antwort weiß, und wir immer noch von Fragen zur Gebärdensprache überrannt werden, können wir uns immer noch überlegen, ob wir der richtige Ansprechpartner für solche Fragen sein wollen. Heute sehe ich hier noch kein Problem.

Wenn wir keine Ahnung haben, sollten wir uns bei solchen Fragen eben etwas zurückhalten, auch was das Voten angeht.

Man könnte freilich argumentieren, dass eine rein auf Text basierte Seite wie unsere vielleicht nicht so geeignet sei, aber auch das relativiert sich schnell. Überlassen wir das doch einfach den Leuten, die eine Antwort schreiben. Man kann Gebärden durchaus beschrieben, zeichnen, fotografieren und sogar filmen. Das alles kann hier prima eingebunden werden. Viel besser noch als bei Fragen nach der Aussprache.

Comment: Die deutsche Gebärdensprache ist keine Ausdrucksform der deutschen Sprache. Sie ist eine völlig andere Sprache.

Comment: @PiedPiper: wir sprechen hier nicht über die englische oder japanische Gebärdensprache.

Comment: Ich sehe auch kein Problem darin, dass manche Fragen offen bleiben, weil niemand eine Antwort weiß. Vielleicht kommt die Antwort nach 6 Monaten.

Comment: Takkat, welche regionale Ausprägung der Gebärdensprache wir besprechen, ist irrelevant. @PiedPiper hat Recht: DGS ist mit deutscher Lautsprache nicht näher verwandt. Niedersorbisch ist hier auch off topic, obwohl es sicher einige hier gibt, die es sprechen und antworten könnten und praktisch der gesamte Sprachraum in Deutschland liegt.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek nein, die regionale Ausprägung ist schon relevant, denn es geht hier um den deutschsprachigen Raum. Ist das bei der Frage nicht zu sehen, dann ist da natürlich nichts *on topic*. Wenn die Mehrheit aber grundsätzlich keine Lust hat, sich mit den massenhaft zu erwartenden Fragen der Gebärdensprache auseinanderzusetzen, bitte schön. Ich meine aber, dass wir solche Fragen nicht pauschal ablehnen sollten. **Wir haben immer noch viel zu wenig Fragen** hier, was auch daran liegt, dass die Community recht fleißig Fragen als *off topic* ablehnt.

Comment: Ich hätte nichts dagegen, DGS explizit als "on topic" aufzunehmen. - Ich verstehe die Frage aber so, dass es um die Klärung geht, ob DGS aktuell on topic ist. Und da bleibe ich bei "nein", denn "DGS" ist ver***t nochmal eine andere Sprache, auch, wenn das hier offenbar kaum jemand anzuerkennen bereit ist oder zumindest für irrelevant hält. :)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: man muss die Frage so verstehen, dass wir als Community aktuell gefragt sind, ob diese Fragen in Zukunft *on* oder *off* topic sein sollen. Nur dazu sind solche Meta-Posts da. Wir als Community alleine bestimmen das. **Es gibt keine andere Instanz als uns, die unser Themenspektrum vorschreibt.** Wenn Du also Niedersorbisch als grundsätzlich *on topic* Thema haben möchtest, musst Du ggf. nur eine positive Abstimmung hier auf Meta herbeiführen (dass es *off topic* sein soll hat auch noch niemand gesagt).

Comment: Der edit war wichtig. So wäre die Frage, die diese Diskussion ausgelöst hat, definitiv on topic. Eine Frage »Wie sagt man x auf DGS« aber nicht.

Comment: @Philipp: Danke. Das habe ich auch gemerkt, ich dachte das sei klar, wenn wir eine Seite über die "German Language" sind.... so kann man sich täuschen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Gebärdensprachen sind eigenständige Sprachen und hier *off-topic*

https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> German Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question-and answer site for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the **German language**. Questions in both, English and German are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Für On-Topic:

Obwohl wir gerade Silvester haben und die Aktivität sicher nicht die größte ist, hat meine Frage in kurzer Zeit eine sehr qualifizierte Antwort bekommen (mit Referenzen), die Nutzerschaft ist also da.

Deutsche Gebärdensprache ist eigenständig in Bezug auf andere Gebärdensprachen (Französische, Britische oder Amerikanische Gebärdensprache) und gehört zum deutschen Sprachraum.

Die Frage im speziellen verweist auf einen Zusammenhang zwischen deutscher Umgangssprache und deutscher Gebärdensprache.

Comment: Was in der Antwort beschrieben wird, nämlich die Kombination von Gebärden, ist nicht spezifisch für die deutsche Gebärdensprache. Du hättest eine ähnlich qualifizierte Antwort vermutlich auch in English SX oder auch bei StackOverflow erhalten können. Die Antwort hat nichts mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun. Wenn du hier eine Frage zur Englischen Sprache stellst, wirst du vermutlich auch eine qualifizierte Antwort erhalten, trotzdem wäre die Frage hier off-topic.

Comment: Dies ist die einzige Argumentation für "ON topic", der ich zumindest teilweise zu folgen bereit wäre: Es geht um einen genau bestimmten möglichen Einfluss der deutschen Lautsprache auf die DGS. - Allerdings müssten dann auch alle anderen Fragen zu deutschen Lehn- und Fremdwörtern in anderen Sprachen ON topic sein. - Daher bleibe ich bei OFF topic.

Answer (score -1):

Deutsche Gebärdensprache (GS) muss on-topic sein. Denn:

1. Gegenteiliges wäre diskriminatorisch. GS ist ein Ausdruck der deutschen Sprache. Den verwendet schlicht eine Minderheit.
2. Wir haben keine aus GS-Experten bestehende Nutzeschaft. Ebenso haben wir keine Nutzeschaft erheblich vieler Experten in alten Schriften. Jedoch erlauben wir Fragen derart [„Mein Opa ließ diese Postkarte, einmal bitte Hilfe, um die Handschrift zu enträstseln.“](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44294/have-been-trying-to-translate-this-hoping-it-some-info-of-a-great-grandfather) und sogar deren Übersetzung.
3. Die verlinkte Frage deutet *explizit* auf eine Beziehung zwischen dem Deuschen und seiner GS. Es geht um den *Guten-Rutsch*-Wunsch. Zumindest halbe Frage ist im Deutschen geankert. So sind aber viele (Japanisch-Deusch, Spanisch-Deutsch, ja Jiddisch-Deusch).

Comment: Man darf sich von dem Adjektiv *deutsch* in *Deutsche Gebärdensprache* nicht täuschen lassen: Bei der Gebärdensprache handelt es sich um eine eigenständige Sprache, wie sich durch nur kurzes Überfliegen der [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Geb%C3%A4rdensprache#Die_Grammatik_der_Deutschen_Geb%C3%A4rdensprache) feststellen läßt. Entlehnungen oder die Zahl der Sprecher spielen dagegen meines Erachtens überhaupt keine Rolle.

Comment: @DavidVogt: die Frage, die diese Meta-Diskussion initiiert hat ("guten Rutsch wünschen"), ist so nur im deutschsprachigen Raum überhaupt denkbar. Es gibt durchaus Fragen, die nur deutschsprachige Gehörlose betreffen und genau solche Fragen sollten wir nicht ausschließen indem wir Gebärdenprache pauschal als *off topic* bewerten. Daduch sind Fragen nach international gültigen Gebärden doch nicht automatisch *on topic*.

Comment: Die erste Aussage ist schlicht falsch. DGS ist kein Ausdruck der deutschen (Laut-)Sprache. Eine andere Schrift, wie im Punkt 2 angesprochen, ist dies jedoch.

Comment: Bei Punkt drei könnte ich dir ja zustimmen. Aber Punkt 1 + 2? Gegenbeispiel: Es gibt keine Seite »Turkish StackExchange«, und in Deutschland lebt die größte türkischsprachige Gemeinde außerhalb der Türkei, was uns wohl zum kompetetesten StackExchange für Türkisch macht. Sind Fragen zur türkischen Sprache deswegen on-topic?

Comment: Ich halte es eher für diskriminierend, DGS unter "Deutsch" zu subsumieren. Das wird der Sprache nicht gerecht und degradiert DGS-Muttersprachler zu Menschen, die nur nicht in der Lage sind, ihre Sprache zu artikulieren und daher andere Hilfsmittel verwenden müssen. - Alle DGS-Muttersprachler, die ich kenne, übersetzen in die deutsche Schriftsprache, wie ich ins Englische...

Comment: @Philipp Die sind on-topic, falls sie mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun haben. Nicht jede ist. Und somit will man nicht, dass DGS on-topic ist, gewünscht ist dass es *nicht automatisch off-topic* ist. Die Beispielsfrage ist zumindest völlig on-topic, du und weiter haben trotzdem fürs Schließen bestimmt.

Comment: Die zwingende Verbindung der Frage mit der deutschen Sprache ist das einzige Argument, das mir einleuchtet. Und die Frage hier in *meta* ist, ob
 deutsche Gebärdensprache on-topic ist, nicht, ob Fragen on-topic sind, die sich auf die deutsche Lautsprache beziehen.

Answer (score -4):

Der eigentliche Grund, warum wir Fragen als off-topic¹ schließen, ist, dass die Nutzerschaft dieser Seite keine besondere Expertise aufweist, die ihr erlauben würde, diese Fragen zu beantworten bzw. Antworten zu beurteilen.

Dies ist klar der Fall für Gebärdensprache.
Unsere Nutzerschaft hat nicht mehr Expertise in diesem Thema als zufällig von der Straße gepickte Leute (im deutschen Sprachraum).
Nach meinem Wissen hat die deutsche Gebärdensprache mit der gesprochenen deutschen Sprache weniger gemein als Englisch.
Wenn zum Beispiel jemand eine falsche Antwort auf besagte Frage gibt, können wir dies ohne intensive eigene Recherche nicht bemerken.

---

<sup>¹ … und damit meine ich nicht die Zweckentfremdung von *off-topic* für seitenspezifische Schließgründe, sondern echte Fälle von »Thema verfehlt«.</sup>

Comment: Das stimmt zwar, aber: Wer hier eine Frage zur Englischen Sprache stellt, kann sehr wohl eine qualifizierte Antwort erhalten. Soviel Expertise würde ich der Nutzerschaft zusprechen. Trotzdem wäre die Frage off-topic.

Comment: @Philipp: Die Frage ist nicht, ob man eine qualifizierte Antwort erhalten kann. Die Frage ist, ob man eine qualifiziertere Antwort als sonstwo erhalten kann. Sonst verlieren wir unseren thematischen Fokus. Außerdem scheint mir, dass Du meinen Schluss ablehnst, weil er zu stark ist.

Comment: Ich bin mit der Argumentation nicht einverstanden. Du argumentierst in deinem Post mit mangelnder Expertise. Du trennst damit »wofür diese Seite vorgesehen ist« von »womit sich die Nutzerschaft auskennt«. Da klingt an, dass Fragen zu Gebärdensprache hier *on topic* wären, wenn die Nutzer sich damit auskennen würden. Das ist aber explizit nicht der Fall. Dann bräuchten wir den thematischen Fokus nicht, den du in deinem Kommentar erwähnst. Wenn ich im Information Security eine Anfängerfrage zu Firewalls stelle, ist das auch OT: Obwohl dort Expertise vorhanden ist, schicken sie einen zu SuperUser

Comment: @Philipp: Stack-Exchange-Seiten sind primär für Communities, nicht für Themen. In den meisten Fällen ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden kaum merkbar, aber manchmal ist er eben doch wichtig. Wenn man auf Basis von »wofür diese Seite vorgesehen ist« operiert, ergeben sich irgendwann unproduktive Diskussionen darüber, was genau z. B. deutsche Sprache, Fotografie oder Grafikdesign eigentlich ist.

Comment: @Philipp: *Wenn ich im Information Security eine Anfängerfrage zu Firewalls stelle, ist das auch OT* – Es ist aber kein Fall von »Thema verfehlt«. Eine Community kann immer noch gewisse Typen von Fragen innerhalb ihrer Expertise ablehnen, weil sie aus anderen Gründen schlecht sind (und da wir seitenspezifischen Schließgründe nur für *off-topic* haben, landen sie dann dort). Wir z. B. lehnen Fragen ab, wo wir nur ein Wörterbuch zitieren bzw. emulieren können. Diese sind trotzdem über die deutsche Sprache.